# How can I view other users pages?

Tags: administration

As an administrator, is it possible through SharePoint, or some other tool, to view the webparts and configuration of other users sites & pages?

Comment: Do you mean their personalizations to webparts and pages.

Comment: Yes... the personalized view.

Answer (score 1):

We used screen shots a lot for resolving defects.  If you have some kind of remote desktop sharing application, that might help.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the normal access control a farm administrator can put you in the Site Collection Administrators group.

Comment: The question relates to personalized views not to being able to view pages in general